# How to "Let's Encrypt" Wildcard SSL certificate on Multiple Servers?

Tags: ssl-certificate

How can I configure WildCard SSL Certificate with `certbot` and copy the same certificate to other servers as well? I'm trying to run a secured Nodejs (Expressjs) application.

Currently, I'm able to do that by creating separate certificates for every subdomain but since I'm moving to Terraform, I can't do it in that way due to subdomain records will be created after the instance resource.

Comment: Just create a `cron` to `rsync` the cert-files to the other server and another `cron` on the destination to reload/restart the service when the files have changed

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit @Virsacer. On which server should I create the wildcard certificate? 

https://marcincuber.medium.com/lets-encrypt-generating-wildcard-ssl-certificate-using-certbot-ae1c9484c101

Following the above tutorial, I can create the certificates successfully. However, I can't just copy. Do you know where the files are located and is it possible to copy that files?